# str_replace is not working on my codebox

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I am having a problem with a str_replace()

**Input value**

```
 <br />
<!-- BEGIN switch_user_authreply --><br />
<div id="mobileActionBar"><br />
    <a href="{U_POST_REPLY_TOPIC}" rel="nofollow" class="navbar"><br />
        <div class="mobileActionLabel">{L_POST_REPLY_TOPIC}</div><br />
    </a><br />
</div><br />
<!-- END switch_user_authreply -->
```

**function used**

```
 $message = preg_replace('~\[code\](.*?)\[/code\]~s', '<textarea as="codebox">'.str_replace("<br />","\n", htmlspecialchars("$1")).'</'.'textarea>', $message);
```

**expected result (where 
 => \n)**

```
<!-- BEGIN switch_user_authreply -->
<div id="mobileActionBar">
    <a href="{U_POST_REPLY_TOPIC}" rel="nofollow" class="navbar">
        <div class="mobileActionLabel">{L_POST_REPLY_TOPIC}</div>
    </a>
</div>
<!-- END switch_user_authreply -->
```

**real result**
(the same as before), the function didn't do anything

Do you have any idea on the problem?

Comment: Why don't you use the `nl2br()` function?

Comment: Where are those `[code]` tags that `preg_replace()` is supposed to match? I can see none.

Comment: Looks to me as if the regex does not match at all...

Comment: @arkascha See my comment, I had the same idea.

Comment: Ah, found it, I guess: your inner `htmlspecialchars()` call converts the contained `<br />` to `&lt;br /&gt;`, so the str_replace()` call does not replace anything.

Comment: @arkascha But still, at the least the `textarea` would show up then.

Comment: No, since the regular expression does not mathc. About the str_replace: this combination of function calls does not make sense: The inner str_replace() call gets a `$1` as argument, however that literal string does not contain any occurrences of `<br />`. only after the evaluation of the inner functions the regex specific logic ab´$1` gets applied, which works, but obviously then the `str_replace()` does not apply any more...

Comment: @arkascha because it is the opposite I want to have..
- Jan [code]content[/code] will be replace by <textarea as="codebox">content</textarea>
-arkascha I removed that, but still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three major issues here:

1. the inner functions `htmlspecialchars()` and `str_replace()` are evaluated *before* the logic of `preg_replace()` applies. That means the `$1` used inside actually is the literal string "$1" and not, as exected, the inner part of the mathing regular expression. That means that *there is not 
    in there that can be replaced*.
2. the inner call to `htmlspecialchars()` would effectively convert all contained "
   " occurrences to "<br />", which again would lead to no match for the call to `str_replace()`, which is why the two function calls have to be swapped.
3. there is no way around this with `preg_replace()`, since all of its arguments must be present and fully evaluated before getting fed into the function call. An alternative here is to use a callback function: this allows to postpone those function calls until the actual execution of the output function call.

This works for me:

```
<?php

$input = <<< EOT
some arbitrary outer text
[code]
<br />
<!-- BEGIN switch_user_authreply --><br />
<div id="mobileActionBar"><br />
    <a href="{U_POST_REPLY_TOPIC}" rel="nofollow" class="navbar"><br />
        <div class="mobileActionLabel">{L_POST_REPLY_TOPIC}</div><br />
    </a><br />
</div><br />
<!-- END switch_user_authreply -->
[/code]
some arbitrary outer text
EOT;

$output = preg_replace_callback(
    '~\[code\](.*)\[/code\]~s',
    function ($m) {
        return 
            '<textarea as="codebox">'
            .htmlentities(str_replace('<br />',"\n", $m[1]))
            .'</textarea>';
    },
    $input
);

print_r($output);
```

The output is:

```
some arbitrary outer text
<textarea as="codebox">


&lt;!-- BEGIN switch_user_authreply --&gt;

&lt;div id=&quot;mobileActionBar&quot;&gt;

    &lt;a href=&quot;{U_POST_REPLY_TOPIC}&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot; class=&quot;navbar&quot;&gt;

        &lt;div class=&quot;mobileActionLabel&quot;&gt;{L_POST_REPLY_TOPIC}&lt;/div&gt;

    &lt;/a&gt;

&lt;/div&gt;

&lt;!-- END switch_user_authreply --&gt;
</textarea>
some arbitrary outer text
```

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help, this was an interesting question, actually. Tricky. :-) And keep in mind: since you received help here yourself it is up to you now to help others in turn. Take your time and only offer answers where you really are sure you understood the question and actually can provide a real answer. But actually one learns quite a lot by helping each other here. So feel welcome, join us!

Answer (score 0):

Wow you are combining a lot of stuff in one go.

Keep in mind that the `preg_replace` only converts the "$1" inside a string value presented for replacement.

What you are doing is effectively this:

```
htmlspecialchars("$1") // equals $1
str_replace("<br />", "\n", "$1"); // which matches nothing
```

I think my approach would be to use `preg_match` rather then replace:

```
<?php

$message = <<<EO_MESSAGE
[code]
 <br />
<!-- BEGIN switch_user_authreply --><br />
<div id="mobileActionBar"><br />
    <a href="{U_POST_REPLY_TOPIC}" rel="nofollow" class="navbar"><br />
        <div class="mobileActionLabel">{L_POST_REPLY_TOPIC}</div><br />
    </a><br />
</div><br />
<!-- END switch_user_authreply -->
[/code]
EO_MESSAGE;


if ( preg_match( '~\[code\](.*?)\[/code\]~s', $message, $matches) ) {

    $found = $matches[1];

    $found = str_replace( '<br />', "\n", $found);
    $found = '<textarea as="code">' . $found . '</textarea>';

    $message = str_replace( $matches[0], $found, $message );
}

print_r( $message );
```

---

And if you want to replace multiple [code] blocks use the `preg_match_all` functionality instead:

```
<?php

$message = <<<EO_MESSAGE
[code]
 <br />
<!-- BEGIN switch_user_authreply --><br />
<div id="mobileActionBar"><br />
    <a href="{U_POST_REPLY_TOPIC}" rel="nofollow" class="navbar"><br />
        <div class="mobileActionLabel">{L_POST_REPLY_TOPIC}</div><br />
    </a><br />
</div><br />
<!-- END switch_user_authreply -->
[/code]
EO_MESSAGE;


if ( preg_match_all( '~\[code\](.*?)\[/code\]~s', $message, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) ) {

    foreach ($matches as $match ) {
        print_r($match);
        $found = $match[1];

        $found = str_replace('<br />', "\n", $found);
        $found = '<textarea as="code">'.$found.'</textarea>';

        $message = str_replace($match[0], $found, $message);
    }
}

print_r( $message );
```

Comment: The issue with this approach is that it replaces only a single occurrence of such a `[code]...[/code]` block, not multiple. Which probably is the reason why the OP chose the replacement function instead. Also the `htmlspecialchars()` call is missing and not that easy to add, since it would prevent the final `str_replace()`call to match anything again...

Comment: I will add an alternative for `preg_match_all` which handles that approach.